# htaccess RewriteCond with HTTP_HOST and specific REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my .htaccess file in my webpage's root dir on my local test server:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /php/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?s=%1 [QSA,L]
```

It translates any URL of myserver.com/php/something.php to myserver.com/?s=something very fine as expected, but now I need I could test it also via my smartphone which IP is static of 192.168.1.11 which I am not able to do.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.1\.11 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /php/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?s=%1 [QSA,L]
```

I need that both my local PC that is running the test server could open my page but also my smartphone so I would be able testing/seeing responsive designs.

Comment: Multiple RewriteCond are joined together using an implicit AND, if you want different behavior you need to explicitly specify so using the `OR` flag.

Comment: OK, but how to - can you provide some example based on my code, please?

Comment: I’d recommend that you remove the third RewriteCond - makes it easier to deal with OR/AND, and it is really rather superfluous - the check for that specific pattern can be handled directly in the RewriteRule, this doesn’t need to be handled via a condition. (Remember to replace %1 with $1 then.) And then join the remaining two conditions via OR, by adding that flag on the first one.

Comment: what about writing your answer as normal solution so I can flag it as the right one (in case it would work)? It would be much easier and much normal response, I guess - please, do that if you can! ;-)